# Dart上のエラーが分からない

Tags: flutter, dart

写真のようなエラーが出るのですが、どう解決すればよろしいでしょうか；：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーが表示されるまでに行った操作手順や、関連するソースコード等を質問に含めた方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> Warning：　CocoaPods　not installed. Slipping pod install

とエラーコードにあるので、CocoaPodsによるエラーだと考えられます。

おそらく、Dart上のエラーとタグから推測するにFlutter開発上のエラーである前提として回答します。

また、M1MacかIntel Mac、Android StudioかVScodeかによって対応も変わってくるそうです。

### Cocoa PodsのInstall

`CocoaPods not installed`が出ている以上、CocoaPodsがInstallされていない可能性があります。

ターミナル上で

```bash
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

でCocoaPodsをInstallしてみてください。

詳細は[公式ページ](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started)にあります。

### Flutter Doctor

ターミナル上で

```bash
$ flutter doctor
```

と入力してFlutter Doctorを起動して、

```bash
[!] Android toolchain
```

という箇所があったら、`Flutter run`をしてから、Android　Stuidoを閉じてターミナル上で

```bash
$ open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

と入力して、再度Android Stuiodを開くと解決するそうです。
[参考文献](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446186/flutter-warning-cocoapods-not-installed-skipping-pod-install-even-while-inst)

### その他

他、Flutter3になってから同様なエラーの報告がZennにありました。M1MacとIntell Macによって対応が異なるそうなので、以下、2つの記事から対応してみてください

- [M1Mac](https://zenn.dev/hi_okuma/articles/1193c0b5df8a29)
- [Intell Mac](https://zenn.dev/ryouhei_furugen/articles/ace89d5796e28e)